# How to disable auto building in MSVC on launch?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When ever i launch MSVC solution file, visual studio is trying to build. My project file is big and takes time for building.

So, i do not want VS to build solution on launch. Is there any way?

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ReSharper?  If yes, go to `Extensions -> ReSharper -> Options` and make sure `Run build after solution is loaded` is unchecked.

[image: ReSharper Options]

If you don't have ReSharper or the checkbox is already unchecked, go to `Tools -> Import and Export Settings...` and select `Reset all settings`

[image: Reset all settings]

If that does not work, try running a `Repair` on the VS installation and disable or uninstall all extensions and plug-ins.

Also, try opening a different, smaller project and see if there is a problem with all projects or just yours.